# Op- amp comparators and temperature dependent resistor

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, tdr

[image]The circuit in Fig 1 consists of a temperature dependent resistor (TDR). Compute the:

1. temperature at which the comparator will change state.
   2)supply voltage required for a 40°C trip point in Figure 1.
   [image: figure 1]

I have researched and found the text book [page 83](https://www2.mvcc.edu/users/faculty/jfiore/OpAmps/OperationalAmplifiersAndLinearICs_3E.pdf)the question was taken from but there is no example to go about this problem. Kindly assist.

edit:
I have attached my answer if anyone can help.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: To get you started, make a formula for the resistance of the TDR and use that to make a formula for the voltage at the center of the voltage divider.  Post the result here and show your work and people can either help you or confirm your answers.  We don't mind homework questions here, but there is a minimum effort requirement.

Comment: Your work looks reasonable. Do you have a question about it?

Comment: @ScienceGeyser I just need confirmation if I am right.

Comment: It's correct if the TDR has a positive temperature coefficient. I'd say it's given by the 10 Ohms/C with no negatives in there.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser thank you

Comment: hi chaperone, i would you suggest you make the post more explicit, i can't tell whether you are stuck on something or you are just asking people to confirm what you just made is right